# How to insert file, object to excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel

I can insert an image to excel worksheet with AddShape method.

But when I try and insert an object like a file, I am getting an error like hsresult.

How can I insert rar or text or any other file type to Excel programaticaly ? I am using csharp and I am referencing excel interop to my project.

**Please help me , how can i insert object to excel via AddObject method using chsarp.**

Comment: This is not cuplicate.This is uniq question, please help me.

Comment: :what do you mean of adding rar file? what do you want to do with rar file in Excel?

Comment: Think about it ; you have a google earth kmz file (it is a zip file actually) , and you need to add this kmz file to excel. So after you open your excel file, you can click to kmz when you need. You should not to know any directory name which kmz in placed or you dont have to manage one more files Lets try to open excel and, go to Insert menu and click "Object". Choose your file and see result. You can see your file as an icon. And you can save this excel file when containing selected file. So next time you dont need to search any file from any place..